# How to get Age Range and Gender of Ad Group via Google Ads API?

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I am using Google Ads API SDK for Python. I want to get Age Range and Gender target for each Ad Group. I spent hours on Google Ads API docs but still really cannot understand how to find that.
Could you guys please give me a suggestion? A sample GAQL query would be nice ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Apologies, I misunderstood.

You need to use the ad_group_criterion along with the age_range_view to get the metrics associated with each audience you mentioned.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT ad_group_criterion.gender.type, ad_group_criterion.age_range.type, metrics.clicks, age_range_view.resource_name 
FROM age_range_view
```

You can use either the gender view or the age range view:
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v7/gender_view

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it :( I am new to Python, so I am sorry if this is obvious, but I cannot understand how it works. If you could provide an example code, that will be great.

Comment: I misunderstood, apologies. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Can I use the 'Ad Group Criterion' table if I only need 4 columns: ad_group_id, campaign_id, gender_type and age_range_type?

Comment: In age_range_view, it is not returning any data for ad_group_criterion.gender.type. @ToànĐoàn Did you get both data in single query?